# Reading an array from POF Stream

Tags: java, arrays, deserialization

Is there a way to know the number of elements from an array in a POF Stream?

I need to use the PofReader to read an array. However, I don't know how to get the size to match the number of elements in the POF stream.

```
public class BasicTypesPofSerializer implements PofSerializer {

private static final int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;

private static final int ID = 0;

private static final int BOOLEAN1 = 1;
private static final int BOOLEAN2 = 2;
private static final int BOOLEAN3 = 3;

private static final int BYTE1 = 4;
private static final int BYTE2 = 5;
private static final int BYTE3 = 6;

private static final int SHORT1 = 7;
private static final int SHORT2 = 8;
private static final int SHORT3 = 9;

private static final int INT1 = 10;
private static final int INT2 = 11;
private static final int INT3 = 12;

private static final int FLOAT1 = 13;
private static final int FLOAT2 = 14;
private static final int FLOAT3 = 15;

private static final int DOUBLE1 = 16;
private static final int DOUBLE2 = 17;
private static final int DOUBLE3 = 18;

private static final int NUMBER1 = 19;
private static final int NUMBER2 = 20;

private static final int CHAR1 = 22;
private static final int CHAR2 = 23;
private static final int CHAR3 = 24;

private static final int STRING1 = 25;
private static final int STRING2 = 26;

private static final int DATE1 = 28;
private static final int DATE2 = 29;

private static final int OBJECT1 = 31;
private static final int OBJECT2 = 32;

private static final int CLASS1 = 34;
private static final int CLASS2 = 35;

@Override
public Object deserialize(PofReader reader) throws IOException {

    BasicTypes basic = new BasicTypes();

basic.number2 = (Number[]) reader.readObjectArray(NUMBER2, new Number[ARRAY_SIZE]);
basic.string2 = (String[]) reader.readObjectArray(STRING2, new String[ARRAY_SIZE]);
basic.obj2 = (Serializable[]) reader.readObjectArray(OBJECT2, new Serializable[ARRAY_SIZE]);

reader.readRemainder();
    return basic;
    }
}
```

As you can see in this sample of code, I have several arrays. The number of elements in each one may or may not be the same. I need to know of a way to get the size match the number of elements so I won't get elements cut off or null positions.
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/coherence/330/com/tangosol/io/pof/PofReader.html), you don't even have to know the size. Passing e.g. new Number[0] should work.

Comment: I'm passing a 10, and reading an array with only 2 elements I get 8 fields with null

Comment: Did you try using new Number[0]?

Comment: No problem, I've posted the solution as an answer below so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/coherence/330/com/tangosol/io/pof/PofReader.htm), you don't even have to know the size. You could do:

```
@Override
public Object deserialize(PofReader reader) throws IOException {

    BasicTypes basic = new BasicTypes();

    basic.number2 = (Number[]) reader.readObjectArray(NUMBER2, new Number[0]);
    basic.string2 = (String[]) reader.readObjectArray(STRING2, new String[0]);
    basic.obj2 = (Serializable[]) reader.readObjectArray(OBJECT2, new Serializable[0]);

    reader.readRemainder();
    return basic;
    }
}
```

I think you could even try passing null.